# How to retrieve pdf file from firebase and display this pdf in fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in android and firebase. 
I try to find some informations, but it dont help me..

Here is an image, how it shall look like, what I want to archieve. 
[The Example what I want to archieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNtzi.jpg)

I want to click on the "scrollbar" box on an item, and display this pdf file below. 
My idea was, to put the files in firebase,

and find a method, to get all "files", which are pdf, and then dynamically create the "list-elements" of the scrollbar like in the image-example.

When I click in one, the pdf shall be displayed below the box in this fragement.

Does anybody have an idea, how to realize it? Like to get a reference link of the firebase http, to display in `WebView`?

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wiki, container, false);

```
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String myPdfUrl = "exampleSite.pdf";
    String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    return view;
```

The order URL is something like `gs://teste-1b31d.appspot.com` in firebase, where I already uploaded some files..

For help, I would be very happy. Thanks